# Who is the Daily Days' Chief Editor?

Tags: baccano

In *Baccano!*, "Daily Days" is both newspapers and an information office. In the anime, its president, chief editor, and chairman stays hidden behind a mount of files.

Who is he?

[image: pile of books]

Comment: What do you mean by "Who is he?" ?

Comment: i'd like to know his identity and history if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's the president of the Daily Days. He runs the newspaper and the Information Brokerage. Nothing more, nothing less. He never appears outside of that context not even in the novels.

And the only mentions of people seeing him are a girl on the street calling the cops when she saw him climbing through the window of the News Paper building since he physically can't get around the stacks of papers in his office and has to come and go through the window.

And when he met Keith Gandor for a private interview.

(Rubik sees him in the anime, but that's anime-only).